# Different UI for the SelectedItem and the ItemTemplate for Silverlight ComboBox

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-3.0

Basically I'm just looking for a 'SelectedItemTemplate' in the SL3 ComboBox. Unfortunately, that doesn't exist.

What I want is for the SelectedItem to look like this: Value

And the items in the dropdown box to look like this: Value + extra information

The latter is easily enough done by using the ItemTemplate, but the SelectedItem looks like that too. How can I prevent / fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `.`[`SelectionBoxItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.selectionboxitemtemplate.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, something like that, but the SL3 ComboBox doesn't seem to have that property?

Comment: Odd... I don't have SL3 to test on here, but it is listed in the MSDN documentation (even though SL3 is not listed in the "other versions" box: add (VS.96) before the .aspx in my link). Maybe it's an issue with the beta? Try ignoring intellisense, if that's what you're going by, and just compiling with it anyway.

Comment: Alas... I tried it and got this: XamlParseException. AG_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 96 Position: 135] And yes, line 96 is the line with the SelectionBoxItemTemplate ;-)

Comment: UNKNOWN_ERROR suggests to me that it is a Beta bug. I guess you have to wait for them to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by creating your own SelectionBoxItemTemplate attached property and then defining a new style/control template for the ComboBox which uses that template in the content presenter for the selection box area.

Here's a suitable attached property:

```
public class ComboBoxExt
{
    public static DataTemplate GetSelectionBoxItemTemplate(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DataTemplate) obj.GetValue(SelectionBoxItemTemplateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectionBoxItemTemplate(DependencyObject obj, DataTemplate value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectionBoxItemTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionBoxItemTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectionBoxItemTemplate", typeof (DataTemplate), typeof (ComboBoxExt),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

To update the ComboBox control template, look for the element named `ContentPresenter` inside one called `ContentPresenterBorder` (you can find the default style for ComboBox [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)). You need to remove the name of the ContentPresenter (otherwise the ComboBox will set values for its properties explicitly through code, ignoring the databindings that you set).

Here's what the ContentPresenter element in the adjusted control template should look like:

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                  Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  ContentTemplate="{Binding (a:ComboBoxExt.SelectionBoxItemTemplate), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
</ContentPresenter>
```

Finally, to use this, you would do something like:

```
<ComboBox 
   Style="{StaticResource MyAdjustedComboBoxStyle}"
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDropDownAreaTemplate}"
   Behaviors:ComboBoxExt.SelectionBoxItemTemplate="{StaticResource MySelectionAreaTemplate}">
```

Comment: This solution deserves a +50. I just ran into this issue with a SL project, figured this was a long-shot but it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

`SelectionBoxItemTemplate` is available in Silverlight4, but unable to set the value of this property from code-behind as it is a read-only property. Also it is not a dependency property, so unable to set value using `comboBox.SetValue()` method. Any idea on how to assign value to this property in code-behind?